# C++ - How to implement a Mask R-CNN?

Tags: c++, instance, mask, segment

I need to implement a custom Mask-RCNN in C++ to perform instance segmentation on a custom dataset. Since I'm a beginner, I just know the theory, but I really don't know how to apply it.

Could you give me some guidelines to start my project? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a beginner, doing machine learning in C++ will be a very high bar.

Pretty much all the packages out there use python for the API. Tensorflow allows running the session API in C++, but you need to build the graph in python. And dealing with the build of tensorflow will be a pain.

Get the Mask-RCNN from its github, run it in python, understand it. Check that the license fits your need. Then, assuming your project is in C++, brush up on bindings between C++ and python. Have your C++ make calls to a python layer that imports Mask-RCNN.

Any other approach will offer significant hurdles to a beginner.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. I got the Mask-RCNN from GitHub and for now I'm going to create a custom dataset, like [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/07/building-mask-r-cnn-model-detecting-damage-cars-python/), to see what happens.
Later I'll try to manage the C++ project as you said.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Is great for making ML applications.

Some concepts you'll need to learn are

- Matrix Layouts ( Row Major, Column Major)
- Vectors
- Matrix Vector Multiplication
- Matrix Matrix Multiplication

The most important thing is cache locality. Decreasing cache misses ESPECIALLY in matrix multiplication (gemm and gemv) will be the determining factor of your networks speed. Using a naive matrix multiplication (n^3 loads) that is cache friendly is going to provide you with the best results.